# Created Date Table in PowerBi, Joined it, but Data is missing

Tags: excel, join, powerbi

GitHub Repository with [power bi file](https://github.com/RanaDataViz/pbi)

Created Date Table in PowerBi per [these instructions](https://kohera.be/blog/business-intelligence/how-to-create-a-date-table-in-power-bi-in-2-simple-steps/)

Joined the tables
[image]

When I create simple table with Month and Matches, Month is blank

[image]

However if I display Month by itself, then the values show. HELP!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the Standard Date used in the relationship is of Text datatype. Power BI can't rationalize a relationship between a date and a string.

[image: Data type]

I would change the relationship to use the Date column of the Calendar.

[image: New relationship]

The month names should show in the table.

[image: Table]